# How do I define parameters in a convolution equation?

Tags: matlab, audio, mono, signal-processing, convolution

I am trying to compute the convolution of a sound signal **without** using the built in `conv` function but instead using arrays. `x` is the input signal and `h` is are the impulse responses. However, when I run my other main function to call onto `my_conv` I am getting these errors:

> ```
> Undefined function or variable 'nx'.**
>
> Error in my_conv (line 6)
> ly=nx+nh-1;
>
> Error in main_stereo (line 66)
> leftchannel = my_conv(leftimp, mono); % convolution of left ear impulse response and mono
> ```

This is my function `my_conv`:

```
function [y]=my_conv(x,h)
  x=x(:);
  h=h(:);
  lx=length(x);
  lh=length(h);
  ly=nx+nh-1; 
  Y=zeros(nh,ny);
  for i =1:nh
    Y((1:nx)+(i-1),i)=x;
  end
  y=Y*h;
```

What changes should I make to fix these errors and get this code running?

I am trying to immplement the function into this code:

```
input_filename = 'speech.wav'; 
stereo_filename = 'stereo2.wav'; 
imp_filename = 'H0e090a.dat';
len_imp = 128; 
fp = fopen(imp_filename, 'r', 'ieee-be'); 
data = fread(fp, 2*len_imp, 'short');
fclose(fp); 
[mono,Fs] = audioread(input_filename); 
if (Fs~=44100)
end
len_mono = length(mono); 


leftimp  = data(1:2:2*len_imp); 
rightimp = data(2:2:2*len_imp); 
leftchannel  = my_conv(leftimp, mono); 
rightchannel = my_conv(rightimp, mono);

leftchannel  = reshape(leftchannel , length(leftchannel ), 1); 
rightchannel = reshape(rightchannel, length(rightchannel), 1); 
norml = max(abs([leftchannel; rightchannel]))*1.05; 
audiowrite(stereo_filename,  [leftchannel rightchannel]/norml, Fs);
```

Comment: The error message is telling you what to do.  `nx` is undefined. So define it. Other than that, `nh` is also undefined

Comment: Since you're not using `lx` and `ly` anywhere in your code, it seems that you wanted to name them `nx` and `ny` respectively

Comment: Even when defining /changing the nh and nx to lh and lx my code is still not running @SardarUsama

Comment: Change `lh`, `lx` and `ly` to `nh` , `nx` and `ny` respectively

Comment: Errors still persist after doing so @SardarUsama

Comment: What equation are you trying to implement here? Include that equation in your question. Also  tell exactly what values of  `x` and `h` are you using. Edit this information into your question to make your  problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SardarUsama I have just edited my question to include the other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @[SardarUsama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698672/sardar-usama) in comments, the error

> ```
> Undefined function or variable 'nx'.
> Error in my_conv (line 6) ly=nx+nh-1;
> ```

tells you that the variable `nx` has not been defined before before its usage on the line `ly=nx+nh-1`. Given the naming of the variables and their usage, it looks like what you intended to do was:

```
nx = length(x);
nh = length(h);
ny = nx+nh-1;
```

After making these modifications and solving the first error, you are likely going to get another error telling you that

> ```
> error: my_conv: operator *: nonconformant arguments
> ```

This error is due to an inversion in the specified size of the `Y` matrix. This can be fixed by initializing `Y` with `Y = zeros(ny, nh);`. The resulting `my_conv` function follows:

```
function [y]=my_conv(x,h)
  nx=length(x);
  nh=length(h);
  ny=nx+nh-1; 

  Y=zeros(ny,nh);
  for i =1:nh
    Y((1:nx)+(i-1),i)=x;
  end
  y=Y*h;
```

Note that storing every possible shifts of one of the input vectors in the matrix `Y` to compute the convolution as a matrix multiplication is not very memory efficient (requiring O(NM) storage). A more memory efficient implementation would compute each element of the output vector directly:

```
function [y]=my_conv(x,h)
  nx=length(x);
  nh=length(h);
  if (nx < nh)
    y = my_conv(h,x);
  else
    ny=nx+nh-1; 

    y = zeros(1,ny);
    for i =1:ny
      idh = [max(i-(ny-nh),1):min(i,nh)]
      idx = [min(i,nx):-1:max(nx-(ny-i),1)]
      y(i) = sum(x(idx).*h(idh));
    end
  end
```

An alternate implementation which can be more computationally efficient for large arrays would make use of the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) and use the [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform):

```
function [y]=my_conv2(x,h)
  nx=length(x);
  nh=length(h);
  ny=nx+nh-1; 

  if (size(x,1)>size(x,2))
    x = transpose(x);
  end
  if (size(h,1)>size(h,2))
    h = transpose(h);
  end
  Xf = fft([x zeros(size(x,1),ny-nx)]);
  Hf = fft([h zeros(size(h,1),ny-nh)]);

  y = ifft(Xf .* Hf);
```

Comment: After making the above changes. I am getting these errors.                        Error using zeros
Requested 40128x40001 (12.0GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation
of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become
unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.

Error in my_conv (line 7)
  Y=zeros(ny,nh);

Error in main_stereo (line 66)
leftchannel  = my_conv(leftimp, mono); % convolution of left ear impulse response and
mono ..... I just changed my question to make it more clear. @SleuthEye

Comment: The formulation you provided for the convolution is not the most memory efficient, so while it works for small arrays I'm not surprised that it would run out of memory with two arrays of ~40000 elements each.

Comment: How would you suggest changing it? @SleuthEye

Comment: Instead of defining a matrix `Y`, the basic approach would be to compute the convolution sum for each element of `y`. A more advanced way would make use of the FFT.

Comment: could you edit your answer to show this ! Would be greatly appreciated.@SleuthEye